# Reaffirm or disprove my hypothesis

Tags: geometry

Given a trapezoid $ABCD$, we must prove that its midsegment $EF$ ($E$ being the midpoint of $AD$ and $F$ the midpoint of $BC$) is parallel to the line on which $AB$ is located. Thus, we propose a vector basis $\mathcal{B} = \{ \vec{a}, \vec{b} \}$, so that $\vec{AB} = \vec{a}$ and $\vec{AD} = \vec{b}$. It follows that

\begin{align*}
\vec{BD} &= \vec{BA} + \vec{AD} = -\vec{a} + \vec{b} \\
\vec{BC} &= \vec{BD} + \vec{DC} = -\vec{a} + \vec{b} + k\vec{a} \\
\vec{BF} &= \frac{1}{2} \vec{BC} = -\frac{1}{2}\vec{a} + \frac{1}{2}\vec{b} + \frac{1}{2}k\vec{a} \\
\vec{BE} &= \vec{BA} + \vec{BE} = -\vec{a} + \frac{1}{2}\vec{b} \\
\vec{EF} &= \vec{EB} + \vec{BF} = \vec{a} - \frac{1}{2}\vec{b} - \frac{1}{2}\vec{a} + \frac{1}{2}\vec{b} + \frac{1}{2}k\vec{a} = \frac{1}{2}\vec{a} + \frac{1}{2}k\vec{a} = \frac{1}{2}\vec{a}(1 + k).
\end{align*}

**Explanation of $k$:** Since the lines on which $AB$ and $DC$ are located are parallel **by the definition** of trapezoid, we can then express $\vec{DC}$ with $\vec{a}$. So we introduce a number $k$, with property $k \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ (we can't let $k \le 0$ because then $\vec{DC} = \vec{0}$ or some negative value, which does not suit the definition of a trapezoid). Thus, $\vec{DC}$ can be expressed as $k\vec{a}$.

We have proven that $EF$ is parallel to $AB$, since all we need to express $\vec{EF}$ is $\vec{a}$, meaning that vectors $\vec{AB} = \vec{a}$ and $\vec{EF}$ are parallel. All good.

But I've noticed an interesting detail in the expression $\frac{1}{2}\vec{a}(1 + k)$. Since $k > 0$ the sum in the brackets will be more than $1$, meaning that the real number with which we multiply $\vec{a}$ will be more than $\frac{1}{2}$. **My hypothesis (of which I have possible proof): trapezoid's midsegment is always more than half of the length of $AB$.** This seems sensible, as it is also easy to prove that for a triangle $\triangle ABC$ (let $\mathcal{B} = \{ \vec{a}, \vec{b} \}$, so that $\vec{AB} = \vec{a}$ and $\vec{AC} = \vec{b}$ and the midsegment has $E$ and $F$ as its endpoints) the midsegment is **always** $\frac{|AB|}{2}$ as $\vec{EF} = \frac{1}{2}\vec{a}$.

If I'm wrong, please correct me, and if I'm correct, let me know (and give some additional insight). Thank you in advance.

Comment: Trapezoid midsegment is *exactly* the arithmetic mean of the two bases. The proof is trivial

Comment: @Raffaele Thank you for the clarification. Could you please provide the deduction of this claim (I only operated with $k\vec{a}$ and don't see another way)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already observed *in a triangle the midsegment is half the third side*.

So referring to the picture below we have

$$EG=\frac12 DC,\;GF=\frac12 AB$$

Therefore
$$EF=EG+GF=\frac12 DC+\frac12 AB=\frac12(DC+AB)$$

Hope this is useful

$$...$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it also like this: we know that $\overrightarrow{r_E} = {1\over
2}(\overrightarrow{r_A}+\overrightarrow{r_D})$ and
$\overrightarrow{r_F} = {1\over
2}(\overrightarrow{r_B}+\overrightarrow{r_C})$.

So we have:
$$ \overrightarrow{EF}  =
\overrightarrow{r_F}-\overrightarrow{r_E}= {1\over
2}(\overrightarrow{r_A}+\overrightarrow{r_D} -
\overrightarrow{r_B}-\overrightarrow{r_C}) = \overrightarrow{BA}
+\overrightarrow{CD}$$ As you said we have, since $AB||CD$ that
$\overrightarrow{CD} = k\overrightarrow{BA}$ and thus
$$\overrightarrow{EF} = (1+k)\overrightarrow{BA}$$
So $EF||AB$.